# React, Material-UI: How to composition functional component with customized props using typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui, react-props, high-order-component

I'm trying to make MyCustomButton compositioning with Button in Material-ui

```
import React from "react";
import { Button, ButtonProps } from "@material-ui/core";

interface MyButtonProps {
  'aria-label': string, // I'd like to add a aria-label as required property
  myOptionalProperty?: string
}

export default function MyButton(buttonProps: ButtonProps, myButtonProps: MyButtonProps) {
  return (
    <Button {...buttonProps, ...myButtonProps} />
  );
}
```

And I've got an error code following:
**Parsing error: expression expected.**

I've get some information via [official documents in material-ui](https://material-ui.com/guides/composition/), but I haven't done composition.

full code is in https://codesandbox.io/s/jolly-dawn-keuj5

Does anyone give me some solution?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guessing you don't need to pass two props to `<Button />`

```
import React from "react";
import { Button, ButtonProps } from "@material-ui/core";

interface MyButtonProps {
  title: string,
  myOptionalProperty?: string
}

export default function MyButton<P extends ButtonProps>(myButtonProps: MyButtonProps) {
  return (
    <Button {...myButtonProps as P} />
  );
}
```

---

Try it online:

[image: Edit adoring-haibt-8xrfe]

---

Info me if this doesn't fit your demand or I missed something important